# Regression predictor from count of categorical variables?

Tags: regression, bayesian, python, categorical-encoding

Let's say I have the following strings and associated target variables:

```
PVADDHJ         98.58
LMIJLFPA        98.89
PNI             97.86
YZDYI           100.98
OXFBI           100.99
OPGWQJ          102.43
JDUKN           100.76
ZWDTXHZ         100.09
URJFIT          98.05
VWYWBWUIR       99.76
```

Python code to generate this:

```
import numpy as np

chars = list('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ')
n = 10

for i in range(n):
    np.random.seed(i)
    n_chars = np.random.randint(3,10)
    rand_chars = "".join(np.random.choice(chars, size=n_chars))
    rand_target = np.random.normal(100,1)
    
    print(f"{rand_chars:15s} {rand_target:.2f}")
```

The above example is random, but let say I have an actual dataset where there is a relationship between the strings and the target variable.

Using counts of the individual characters (or just a binary value for each character to indicate whether it's included), I want to predict the values of the target variable.

One way to do this would be a linear regression with one hot encoding for each character and solve for the value of each variable plus a constant.  If this were binary classification, I could use logistic regression with one hot encoding and I believe Naive Bayes would also work.

However, I'm wondering if there is something similar to Naive Bayes that would work for regression in this case, maybe starting with an overall distribution of the target values, and then refining it based on which characters are in the string.  I think this would lead to different predictions than the one hot encoding approach.

*Updating to provide some more context:*  I'm learning about sentiment analysis and I'm curious whether simple counts of certain words are sufficient over more advanced models. I'm trying to figure out how to treat situations that include words that are somewhat contradictory to each other with respect to the target value.  The example above is just an attempt to illustrate the idea in a simple way.

Comment: Why have an example where it seems that the construction gives no relationship between the strings and the values?  Anything you do must give a wrong answer, and doing different things is likely to give different wrong answers

Comment: It's just an example.  I've updated the question to note that I'm not trying to predict random values with random values.

Answer (score 0):

The starting point to me is to have $26$ features, one for each letter of the English alphabet, where your value of the feature is a count of how many times that letter appears in the string. This seems to have an advantage over just an indicator of whether or not a letter appears in the string, since multiple instances could be meaningful. You then can add interactions or other functions of those features, should those be wrranted.

The order of the letters could matter, depending on the circumstances, so you might want to consider more sophisticated methods that account for the sequential nature of the strings. Then again, maybe you have reason to believe that just the letter count matters.

Comment: I updated the question to provide the context (sentiment analysis).  I see from googling it that one approach is just to calculate a ratio of positive to negative words, however, I'm looking for something that generalizes for continuous target variables.  The counting/one hot encoding method would be basically the same for classification and regression, but I would think there's a way to start with a prior distribution and then update it based on which words/letters are included.  I'm just not sure how to go about it exactly.

Comment: Ratio of positive to negative words is a viable feature whether the target is continuous or not. @SuperCodeBrah